# Downloading File error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have used local storage for file storing. I have created table of file, in which **title, path, card_id** rows stored.

```
$request->file('file')->storeAs('public/upload',$files->getClientOriginalName());
```

i.e:**passport.png** stored at */home/dhruv/MyProject/storage/app/public/upload/passport.png*

Above works fine but I'm getting error while downloading file.
in controller...

```
    public function getDownload($file_id)
    {

        $file = File::find($file_id);
        //print_r($file);    
            return response()->download($file->path);
             /*  return response()->download(
                $file->path,
                    $file->name,
                    [],
                    'inline'//attachment
                );*/

    }
```

I tried many downloading methods but any didn't work fine.
I am getting this error.

> *Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException:
>   The file
>   "/home/dhruv/MyProject/storage/public/upload/passport.png"
>   does not exist in file
>   /home/dhruv/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php on
>   line 37*

I dont know why it is searching at **/home/dhruv/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php** since i have inserted correct path.

So suggest any method for downloading ..

Comment: Please find you image this path "/home/dhruv/MyProject/storage/public/upload/passport.png"

Comment: do you have this `/home/dhruv/MyProject/storage/public/upload/passport.png` file

Comment: Yes,That works fine

Comment: show us your folder structure where this image exists

Comment: @Sohel0415 See in my post what i just updated

Comment: path are different,

Comment: @Sohel0415 Ya, Sorry for incorrect  path , But still i m getting error

Comment: try `dd($file)` and show us, and it would be much better if you could share your folder structure of you storage folder where image is

Comment: @Sohel0415 i tried that one but i m getting large string and if you want to see structure then .. Myproject->storage->public->upload->passport.png same as path

Comment: error says your path are incorrect, so if you want us to help, then you need to give something elaborate. please show `dd($file)` and your storage structure.

Answer (score 0):

`return response()->download(Storage::get($file->path));`

Import this before:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

[Laravel Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files)

Or try this:
`return response()->download(storage_path($file->path));`

Comment: i have inserted that too

Comment: what is the actual path, storing in the DB (returned with **$file->path**)?

Comment: see in my post for the same

Comment: the path returned from DB is:
**/home/dhruv/MyProject/storage/public/upload/passport.png**  
It should be:
**public/upload/passport.png**
Then it will work with `Storage::get()` or `Storage::url()`